# Show children of component one by one using angular7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am creating some sort of fake chat to take people through some slightly complicated steps for calculation. Here is a mini sample with only the important parts: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htxjt9

```html
<chat>
  <them>Hi</them>
  <you>Hello!</you>
  <them>Do you want to continue?</them>
  <you><button (click)="this.continue = true">Continue</button></you>
</chat>

<chat *ngIf="this.continue">
  <them>You started the next step</them>
  <them>Thanks</them>
  <you>Awesome</you>
</chat>
```

Once a `<chat>` component initialises, all its direct children need to become visible one by one, with a ~2 second delay.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: To use the deplay operator of rxjs https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html

Comment: But how would I select `<them>` and `<you>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a base class and providers, in order to access `@ContentChildren` made out of different components. This is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvszpq

The important thing was to create a base class for chats:

```js
export abstract class BaseChat {
    visible: boolean = false;
}
```

Then add providers for the chats for `you` and `them`

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChat } from './chat.base';

@Component({
  selector: 'them',
  template: `<div *ngIf="this.visible"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`,
  styles: ['div {margin: 3px; padding: 3px; border: 1px solid black;}'],
  providers: [{provide: BaseChat, useExisting: ChatThemComponent}]
})
export class ChatThemComponent extends BaseChat  {
  @Input("visible") visible: boolean;
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}
```

And then use @ContentChildren to make them all visible.

```js
export class ChatComponent  {
  @ContentChildren(BaseChat) chats !: QueryList<any>;
  private count: number = 0;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.chats.forEach((chat) => {
      this.showChatWithDelay(this.count, chat);
      this.count++;
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you should try the rxjs delay operator. In the example I used a BehaviorSubject. Since it is an example I left out the unsubscription. Please don't forget about it.

See my stackblitz example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvtban

Comment: Ouch, I think my question was slightly unclear to you. The children of the chat need to be shown with a delay. So the `<you>` and `<them>` need to shown with a delay. 

So:
`<them>Hi</them>`
(delay)
`<you>Hello!</you>`.

I was looking to do this with @ContentChildren, and then add a property to `<you>` and `<them>` once they become visible.

Comment: Then you could use the timer of rxjs https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html

Comment: I added a stackblitz with the solution I was looking for. Thank you for helping me!